# Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am sending File and and file path that are both List from controller to the MVC view:

This is my Controller:

```
     public ActionResult Help()
    {

        var releaseNoteFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Content/ReleaseNotes"));

        List<string> month = new List<string>();
        foreach (var releaseNoteFile in releaseNoteFiles)
        {
            month.Add(new Regex("([^A-Z]*)([a-zA-Z]*)").Match(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(releaseNoteFile).Split('.').Last()).Groups[2].Value);
        }
        ViewBag.releaseNoteFilesmonth = month;
        ViewBag.releaseNoteFiles = releaseNoteFiles;

        return View();
    }
```

and this is how show it in the View:

```
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.releaseNoteFilesmonth)
                    {
                        var matchedmonthfile = ViewBag.releaseNoteFiles.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(item), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).FirstOrDefault();
                        @item <a href="@matchedmonthfile">@matchedmonthfile</a>
                        <br />
                    }
```

This is the output I am expecting:

```
OCT - (Link to the file)
NOV - (Link to the file)
Dec - (Link to the file)
```

But I am getting this error in the view:

```
    CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type
```

on this line:

```
    var matchedmonthfile = ViewBag.releaseNoteFiles.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(item), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Have you tried casting it `(delegate)(x => x.Name.Contains(item))`? Perhaps it needs a more elaborate cast (with a `Func` in there)

Comment: I would suggest avoiding `dynamic` invocations altogether, as you can see there's only sort of limited support for in C# and it doesn't compose well with other features. You could easily fix this by using `var releaseNoteFiles = (string[])ViewBag.releaseNoteFiles` and then using the `releaseNoteFiles` variable. You could then avoid using `ViewBag` altogether and instead use `ViewData`, which is a dictionary and you would access the value like this: `var releaseNoteFiles = (string[])ViewData["releaseNoteFiles"]`.

Comment: An easier fix would be a cast - `(Func<string, bool>)(x => ...)`, it just seems kind of ugly in my opinion. The best way would be to avoid doing this logic in a view altogether and prepare the data in the format the view expects.